# How to make component update after call this.props.history.push?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm coding login function that would return to home component after finish save token data to client. 
However, when it go back to homepage, i can not use setState because do not have any componentWillMount or componentDidMount function was called.

Login.js

```js
axios.post(`${Config.API_URL}/users/login`, param)
    .then(response => {
        if (response) {
            this.setState({
                errorCode : response.status
            });
        }
        if(response.status===ErrorCode.SUCCESS){
            var authorization = {"authorization": response.headers.authorization.toString()}
            SessionStorage.saveLocalStorage(authorization);
            this.props.history.push("/");
        }
    })
```

App.js

```js
 componentWillMount() {
    if(SessionStorage.isAuthorization()){
      this.setState({
        isAuthorization : true
      });
    }
    console.log('Component Will MOUNT!')
 }
```

ComponentWillMount() never been called so can not set value for isAuthorization = true anyway.

Comment: Does the `App` component get unmounted? If not then `component{Did/Will}Mount` should not be called. Maybe you need to use the `componentDidReceiveProps` lifecycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes:

1) I'm assuming App.js is actually the holder of all your routes. In this case, App.js is never unmounted from ReactDOM. What you want to do is define a separate component for your "/" route, keeping your App.js clean, focusing only on rendering routes. We will call this component `Home`.

2) I'm not familiar with any library that uses `SessionStorage()`. You might be looking for the `sessionStorage` native JS library. This will have methods called `setItem` and `getItem` for storing and retrieving your token.

3) With the separate `Home` component, we can call `componentDidMount()` to retrieve the token.

With that in mind we can do the following as a template on how you can achieve the functionality you're looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-leftpad-moqs2

### App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

### Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    token: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("authorization");
    if (token) {
      this.setState({
        token: token
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        <p>{this.state.token}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

### Login.js

```
import React from "react";
class Login extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    var token = 210;
    sessionStorage.setItem("authorization", token);
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Thank for your help Christoper Ngo, i think define a separate component is the best idea for my issue, i also want to change the display of menu links in menu base on sessionStorage, now i still keep menu link in App.js, and i should separate them to another component as your suggest.

Comment: Awesome @TuanAnh, I hope you're able to make this work and let me know if you have any questions. If you find that my solution was helpful in resolving your question, please mark it as the answer :)